# Bash/ps: get pid of a running "myscript.sh" child of a certain process

Tags: bash, process, ps

in bash I need to get the pid of a running process whose I know name and parent pid.
In ps' manual I read you can select processes using such arguments:

> --ppid <pidlist>

and

> -C <cmdlist>

So, in order to get the pid of running "myscript.sh" child of $parentpid, I tried:

> ps -C myscript.sh --ppid $parentpid -o pid --no-headers

but I got all the children processes of $parentpid. The -C argument seems to be ignored also if I swap it with the other one.

Any help, expecially avoiding sed and grep and the like?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
pgrep -P $parentpid '^myscript.sh$'
```

Also see [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

Comment: Chapeau. This is exactly what I need.